# How to split an n-size list into smaller lists of maximum 2 items?

Tags: python, list

How to split an n-size list into smaller lists of maximum 2 items? But always starting from 2nd list if it exists to contain previous list last item as first item. The list can be of any length.
Example:

`n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Rezult:

```
"n+1" = [1, 2]
"n+2" = [2, 3]
"n+3" = [3, 4]
"n+4" = [4, 5]
"n+5" = [5, 6]
"n+6" = [6, 7]
```

Comment: `[[i,j] for i,j in zip(n[1:],n[2:])] if len(n) > 2 else [n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[[i, j] for i, j in zip(n[1:], n[2:])]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: To start with [1, 2], I assume is n[0:] ?

Comment: BTW, if this answers your question it would be great if you could accept it for future generations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(n, n[1:])][1:]
print(n)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```

---

To address:

> But always starting from 2nd list **if it exists** to contain previous list last item as first item.

You can use an `if` statement:

```
n = [1, 2]

if len(n) > 2:
    n = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(n, n[1:])][1:]
else:
    n = [n]
    
print(n)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2]]
```